# How to position page number at 2cm from top 2.5cm from right

Tags: header-footer, margins, page-numbering

I need the page number to be 2cm from top and 2.5cm from the right (in the top right corner)

I'm using the below margins

`\usepackage[left=4cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}`

Can you please help me with that

Comment: What are the paper dimensions? Please also clarify what "2cm from top [edge]" implies: Does the baseline have to be 2cm from the top paper edge, or is it the uppermost part of the numerals that count?

Comment: The paper is A4 and the baseline should 2cm from the top edge

Answer (score 2):

The following may be what you want.

```
\pagestyle{myheadings} % Select a suitable page style
\usepackage{geometry}  % Set page geometry parameters
\geometry{a4paper,includehead,showframe, % omit 'showframe' option in real document
          hmargin={4cm,2.5cm},vmargin={2cm,2.5cm}} 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{\headheight}
```

The two `\addtolength` instructions (a) shift the header row up so that the *baseline* of the header is 2cm from the top edge of the paper and (b) adjust the `\textheight` parameter so that the bottom edge of the text block remains 2.5cm above the edge of the sheet of paper.

Be sure to choose -- or set up -- a page style that places the page numbers in the header row.

Here's the result of a full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings} % Select a suitable page style
\usepackage{geometry}  % Set page geometry parameters
\geometry{a4paper,includehead,showframe, % omit 'showframe' option in real document
          hmargin={4cm,2.5cm},
          vmargin={2cm,2.5cm}} 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{\headheight}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla\footnote{bla bla bla}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The page number position is fine, but the top margin is now almost 2.8cm. Can you please confirm this from your side.

Comment: @h.hittini - Are you measuring this from a printed page, printed onto A4 paper? If so, be sure to turn off any print-related settings in your pdf viewer such as "fit to paper size".